# Salesforce Apex unit testing error

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

I am trying to create a Salesforce unit test for a new trigger I created.

```
trigger SOSCreateCaseCustom on SOSSession (before insert) {
    List<Event> aplist = new List<Event>();
    List<SOSSession> sosSess = Trigger.new;
    for (SOSSession s : sosSess) {
        try {
            Case caseToAdd = new Case();
            caseToAdd.Subject = 'SOS Video Chat';
            if (s.ContactId != null) {
                caseToAdd.ContactId = s.ContactId;
            } else {
                List<Contact> contactInfo = [SELECT Id from Contact WHERE Email = :s.AppVersion];
                if (!contactInfo.isEmpty()) {
                    caseToAdd.ContactId = contactInfo[0].Id;
                    s.ContactId = contactInfo[0].Id;
                }
            }
            insert caseToAdd; s.CaseId = caseToAdd.Id;
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
@isTest
private class SOSCreateCaseCustomTest {
    static testMethod void validateSOSCreateCase() {
        String caseSubject = 'SOS Video Chat';

        // set up case to add 
        SOSSession s = new SOSSession();
        insert s;

        Case caseToAdd = new Case(Subject='SOS Video Chat');
        caseToAdd.ContactId = s.ContactId;
        insert caseToAdd;

        Case ca = [SELECT Subject, ContactId from Case where Subject =: caseSubject];
        // Test that escaltion trigger correctly escalate the question to a case
        System.assertEquals(s.ContactId, ca.ContactId);
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error.

```
System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
```

I am new to Apex and I have no idea how to fix this. Any Salesforce and Apex experts out there who can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this one:

```
Case ca = [SELECT Subject, ContactId from Case where Subject =: caseSubject];
```

Because the casSubject may query more then one Case.... You should use List

Comment: that's actually not the issue, I solved this with the help from the salesforce forum. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The following line is causing issue :

Case ca = [SELECT Subject, ContactId from Case where Subject =: caseSubject];

It is returning two cases, the one you inserted in test data and other that is inserted by trigger. So it is having two records for Subject 'SOS Video Chat';

If you change the Subject from 'SOS Video Chat' to any other String it will run successfully.